# Display Activity From Bottom to Top

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-intent

I want to display one `activity` to another from bottom to top animation using `Intent`.

Given me some example for that like below

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(main.this, test.class);
startActivity(i2);
```

with animation bottom to top.

Comment: Not downvoting but those 'pages' are called Activity in Android.

Comment: See, there are so many post here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=using+animation+in+Android

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Define an animation in res/anim/slide_in_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

and another at res/anim/slide_out_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

Then apply these after to call startActivity:

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(main.this, test.class);
startActivity(i2);
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
```

There an introduction to Android animation [here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/129) which may help you further.

Comment: link no longer valid.

Comment: The linked website has 2 series of articles about transitions:
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/transition-animation-part-1/ and
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/manual-layout-transitions-part-1/

Comment: this is awesome. can you you please tell me if i clik on back buttion then activity back Up to Bottom ???

Answer (score 11):

As i googled sliding up transition and landed here but Mark answer is incomplete without transition involved on coming back to the same activity.

Overide finish in activity

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_top,R.anim.slide_in_top);
}
```

finish()

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                finishAfterTransition();
            }else finish();
```

slide_from_top.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

slide_in_top.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First : animate the layout of your activity 1 ,, 
Second : at the end of this aniamtion , Start your second Activity , and animate her Content Layout

Use TranslateAnimation(int fromX,int toX, int fromY , int toY) ;