# Animation while switching Activity in Android?

Tags: android, animation

I want an animation while switching from one activity to another in Android. The animation I'm aiming for is a bottom to top like animation.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes it is possible. [check out this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055984/display-page-from-bottom-to-top) You have to define animations in anim folder than you can overide current animation using

```
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
```

Answer (score 10):

You can set your animation when you go to another activity using this

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Also you can get same animation if you come back from last activity to previous activity by overriding method

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

    }
```

Comment: Actually you have to switch the two lines. Call overridePendingTransition after super.onBackPressed()

Comment: I wonder why they should first `super` be called and `override` only after? From the first glance it seems more logical to first "override" transition and then actual trigger the change, isn't it?

Comment: override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        if (isFinishing) overridePendingTransition(..., ...) }

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to create a style like below

```
<style name="SlideAnimation.Activity" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_from_top</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_to_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_from_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_to_top</item>
</style>
```

If you want to implement this for whole application then use it in app theme like be

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAppBlue</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/SlideAnimation.Activity</item>
</style>
```

And declare the AppTheme in manifest in application tag like below-

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     >
```

And if you want to use for specific activity then apply the theme to that activity in manifest.

Answer (score -1):

You can override the `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`function, and use `finish()` followed by `overridePendingTransition()`.
For example, add the following code in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home: // navigation up.
      finish();
      overridePendingTransition(R.anim.ENTER_ANIMATION, R.anim.EXIT_ANIMATION);
      return true;
    case ....: // implementation of other menu items.
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The other way is overwriting the `public boolean onNavigateUp()` function. But `onNavigateUp()` is only for API level 16 and above.