# Intent Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

please select the following 
Settings->Display->Animation and select "all animations"!
Then can you press Application Icon,Intent wil come as BlowUp Animation,For that Can you send any Samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6056067/964707) from SO. And also refer [this](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/129) too

Bottom animation:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="50%p" 
    android:duration="300"
/>
```

Comment: i saw all those what you are sent .but my requirement is to Animate the Intent as to blow up from centre of the screen,As like when we are click on default Android Icon it wil blow up from Centre..

Comment: I think you want to start animation by clicking your app icon. then you must do it in manifest.  Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5018385/964707

Comment: No i need to use that animation at  my app Homescreen and in that page which is sent by you ,<style name="Animation.MyAwesomeAnimation">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/myawesomeanimation_enter</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/hold_long</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/hold_long</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/myawesomeanimation_exit</item>
</style> can you send @anim/myawesomeanimation_enter and remaining ...

Comment: @anim/hold_long like this are all animation xml files

Comment: can i give that xml path For all four xml like     <style name="Animation.MyAwesomeAnimation">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@layout/animation</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@layout/animation</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@layout/animation</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@layout/animation</item>
</style>

Comment: Ohh..!! finally i got Error with Manifestofile,error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.MyAwesomeTheme').At this line android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAwesomeTheme" at Activity Tag. And Thanks for helping.

Comment: are you create themes.xml like this <style name="Theme.MyAwesomeTheme" parent="Theme.Default">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.MyAwesomeAnimation</item>
</style>

Comment: Yes i Created themes.xml in layout folder

Comment: i AM USING 2.1 IS there any problem with that

Comment: put your themes.xml in values folder of your project

Comment: I got this error after copy that file to values folder
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Default'.

Comment: But Intents are coming regarding on the following code as from right to left and top to bottom when i have given the Xdelta and Ydelta value .BUt I want to get the Blowup Intent Animation from center 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" 
    android:duration="300"
/>Which value can i change to get the Blow UP

Comment: Can you please try this ||  select the following Settings->Display->Animation and select "all animations"! Then can you press Application Icon,Intent wil come as BlowUp Animation,For that Can you send any Samples.

Comment: sorry dont know about you ask