# start activity with left to right mode

Tags: android, android-animation

I am facing a problem .

I have three activities and i need to start new activity with slide left.

```
Activity1

Activity2

Activity3
```

means [image]

when i click to button new activity should not display directly like what android behavior .

i want new activity come from right side and display on current screen.

anyone can provide me guidance.
This is animation or anything else.

Comment: Start activity and then just apply transition effect. Check this http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Animation-on-Switching-between-activities-1392.php And Also this : http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/tutorial-activity-slide-animation/#more-483

Comment: thanks manish please put this in proper ans so i can mark as accepted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6056067/1168654

Comment: @CobraAjgar : I have added my comment to answer. By the way, there is only 2 simple link for accessing source code and more info. And only simple link is not allowed in answer section thats why I send it in comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Start activity and then just apply transition effect.
For more info, how to proceed for this just visit [here](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Animation-on-Switching-between-activities-1392.php) and for source code example visit [this](http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/tutorial-activity-slide-animation/#more-483). For any query, feel free to comment.

Comment: one thing manish i need to start other activity also with the same time ..like click on A activity i need to show B,C sequentially.what should i do

Comment: You can't do without any intent on B Activity. One thing you can that just startActivity (C activity) in onCreate() of Activity B.

Comment: its directly displaying act C.

Comment: Then use startActivity(C Activity) in onStart of B activity and before starting use Thread.sleep or something else who will wait for execute to next line.

Comment: I can't help anymore without source code that you written. So, Ask a different question for different problem. Show there what have you tried and what are you expecting ?

Comment: You should try to give Self-sustained answers and not just links, because if they break your answer will be useless.

Answer (score 106):

I'll try to help you with the following example:

res/anim/trans_left_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<translate 
        android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
        android:toXDelta="0" 
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

res/anim/trans_left_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
         android:fromXDelta="0" 
         android:toXDelta="-100%p" 
         android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

res/anim/trans_right_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p" 
        android:toXDelta="0" 
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

res/anim/trans_right_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
         android:fromXDelta="0" 
         android:toXDelta="100%p" 
         android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

src/Activity2

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_traces);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_left_in, R.anim.trans_left_out);
...}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_right_in, R.anim.trans_right_out);
}
```

Comment: The easiest! Attention: call `super.onBackPressed();` before the overridePendingAnimation otherwise it won't work

Comment: I have been looking for this for a long time :)!! 
transition from Activity1 to Activity2 [ left => right | left <= right ]

Comment: Superb! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

A Better approach is to create a style as follows:

```
<style name="mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/theme</item>
</style>

<style name="theme">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

Then apply this style to your activity in manifest file using the android:theme tag.

Comment: This was helpful from a learning point of view. But practically, I needed to reverse the animation when going backwards, which this didn't do.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is,

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition( R.anim.righttoleft, R.anim.stable );
```

And here is the animation righttoleft.xml,

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
          android:duration="500"
          android:fromXDelta="-100%"
          android:fromYDelta="0%"
          android:toXDelta="0%"
          android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

and stable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
      android:duration="500"
      android:repeatCount="0"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 3):

call `overridePendingTransition` before starting the SecondActivity. It takes as parameters two int `enterAnim,  exitAnim`.

- enterAnim is a resource ID of the animation resource to use for the incoming activity. Use 0 for no animation
- exitAnim is a   resource ID of the animation resource to use for the outgoing activity. Use 0 for no animation.