# Animate two Views together in Android

Tags: android, animation, slide, adview, layout-animation

In my layout I have one button and an AddView on the top of the screen (Image below explain it better). I need the AddView to show only when it is loaded and for that I made an AdListener. But now I want my button to slide down when the AddView is shown. ¿How do I do that? Thank you in advance.

Here is my AdListener

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(){
            adView.bringToFront();
            adView.startAnimation(slide_from_top);
        }

    });
```

Here is my XML animation slide_from_top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
   android:toYDelta="0%p"
   android:duration="1000"/>
```

**EDIT**

Here is my Layouts XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/adView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
   ads:adSize="BANNER"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>   

<Button
   android:id="@+id/MY_BUTTON"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:text="MY_BUTTON" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: this post could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648279/start-activity-with-left-to-right-mode/16648643#16648643

Comment: I just want to Animate the Button, not the whole Activity. Thank you.

Comment: post your xml i can do that for you its quite easy

Comment: @Ammaraly I added my layout's XML code. I don't really know how to do this. I would appreciate if you help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Set the button below to addview

Answer (score 0):

You can control what happens when an animation starts/repeats/ends. So you can start the AdView animation then in the `onAnimationEnd` you can have the button go to View.GONE

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {

}           
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {

}           
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

}
});
```

**Edit:** Just saw that you want the button to slide down rather but still be in view. You can achieve it the same way. Just have button's animation start.

Comment: OK, but how can I make that Button slide and stop below the AdView?

Comment: You need the correct animation in res/anim. That will determine what the animation does. There is plenty of code out there for that. You then apply that to the button. You can set where the animation should start for the button, and where it will end. So it will end below the AdView. In the animation XML you can also set where the animation starts and ends in terms of position.