# when we click on icon/image of any contact, one view slide up from bottom of screen in Lollipop Contact in call details screen?

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

when we click on icon/image of any contact, By default, this view shows full screen.
how will implement following case 
1.View a separate activity with transparent half  when swipe towards   the top it is overlay up-to action bar.
2.swipe down the screen will gone look like lollipop 5.1.1 call details view

Answer (score -1):

Case 1 : For transparent `Activity` try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700683/3227080). You just need to add `Theme.Transparent` and color code `#0000000` in your `styles.xml`

Case 2 : Bottom to Top `Activity` transition use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6056067/3227080) for more detail. You can do Top to Bottom transition on back pressed button.

Comment: case 1 for transparent  for current view of top and half view of below not be transparent see the lollipop  call contact application
case 2 swipe the half view up means its expendable swipe down means that half view of call details gone

Comment: click the particular contact that view should be half and when swipe up means  expendable  up to action bar and swipe down means that view gone

Comment: these answer nothing help me do u lollipop update in your device if u have go to --> phone call -->  contacts -->select one contact-->contact details show  (I am asking this page implementation design )please help me